# Ceiling fan and light Installation

Tags: electrical

Our home was built in the mid 60's. I am trying to install a new fan/light assembly. Currently there are two brown wires and one red wire coming out of the ceiling box. At the very back of the box, I see two black wires that are joined together; however, because there is no white wire, I do not know were to connect the white wire from the new fan.

Comment: What was installed in that box?  Is this in the US or somewhere else?

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box?

Comment: Is there any possibility those brown wires are in fact dirty white?  Can you clean them with soap/water? (with the power off, obviously.)  A photo would be *very* helpful.